# Start Another Activity If There is no Event in This Activity for a Specific Duration

Tags: android

in my app I have two Activities : Main Activity and Ads Activity.
in my Main Activity i want to start Ads Activity if there is no event(button click,listview click,input text,etc..) for specific duration Time( for example 5 second) in Main Activity.
this code starts Ads Activity after 5 second but i want to delay it if there is an event.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdsActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    },5000);

}
```

so how can i do this?

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove callbacks from your handler when an event occurs and post a new runnable. Something like this should work:

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            handler = new Handler();
            postAdAfterDelay();
        }

        // Call this method when a valid event occurs
        private void onEventOccurred() {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            postAdAfterDelay();
        }

        private void postAdAfterDelay() {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdsActivity.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            },5000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to restart the 5 seconds timer on your event:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdsActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
}

private void onYourEvent() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
}
```